# hadoop 2.2.0 libraries are missing?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I've downloaded hadoop2.2.0.jar and added it to my eclipse project as an external jar library.
I get error for:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io;
```

Error: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path cannot be resolved.

Could you please let me know how I can fix it?
I want to create a .jar from my app and run it on Amazon EMR.

Comment: Add the jar to your classpath

Comment: EMR is only 1.x, you can't run it with 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much.
I replaced Hadoop version 2.2.0 with 1.0.3 and the problem get solved.